# I'm trying to reference an image (in a svg code) that is in the same folder that my svg is, but I tried several ways that didn't work

Tags: image, svg, reference

I have this file named `loadingReviewButtonSpinner.gif`, and this file is saved on my computer in the folder where I have my project images (`assets/images`), but I'm trying to reference to this file in my SVG, and it isn't working.

```
<svg
  <image 
    width="70" height="70" 
    transform="translate(30.1 -7.5)" 
    href="loadingReviewButtonSpinner.gif"
    />  
</svg>
```

I have also uploaded this same image (`loadingReviewButtonSpinner.gif`) to a server online, and when I do the reference to the online image, it working 100%

```
<svg
  <image 
    width="70" height="70" 
    transform="translate(30.1 -7.5)"
href="https://tinypic.host/images/2022/05/18/animation_500_l1ki69jf.gif"
    />  
</svg>
```

But I really need it to work for me referring to the folder where my project is.

And I already tried so many options, but none of them is working...

For example, I tried:

- `href="file://loadingReviewButtonSpinner.gif"` (and the variations with the path)
- `href="//..//..loadingReviewButtonSpinner.gif"`
- `href="file:///loadingReviewButtonSpinner.gif"`

Comment: Are you running a web server on your computer? You will need to.

Comment: I running but not for this problem in specific.
Why I need to this? Just to do reference to a local file that is in the same file that my project it running.

Thanks for helping

Comment: I'm not understanding why this is connected, but how can I do this?

Comment: Browsers security models don't allow it. Run a web server access your files via the web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what was said in the comment and it worked.